# Select presselecionado com change do Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

Estou estudando Json e o evento change do Jquery. 
O que eu preciso é o seguinte
Quando o usuário abrir a página já tenha resultados. (no select venha marcado todas)

O html vem vazio e só funciona quando mudo o select para alguma cidade.

```js
   var cidade = "";

$('select').on('change', function() {


  cidade = this.value


  var url = "http://meusite?&cidade="+cidade;

//jsonrodando
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select >
  <option>cidades</option>
  <option value" " selected=" ">todas</option>
  <option value"1"> cidade1</option>
    <option value"2">cidade2</option>
  

</select>
```

O json funciona perfeitamente quando seleciono a cidade correta no select.

Mas ele não vem pre carregado com todas. (Quando a variavel "cidade" na URL vem vazio aparecem todas)

Deve funcionar assim: 
Abre página vem todas as cidades. (isso não funciona).

Usuário muda no select a cidade, e a cidade aparece (isso funciona perfeito);

O que precisa ser mudado no código ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Modifiquei o código.

```js
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $(this).val() + " ";
    });
    console.log(str);
    cidade=str;

    var url = "http://meusite.com?cidade="+cidade;
  
//json rodando perfeito aqui 

  })
  .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select  >
  <option value="2"> cidade 2</option>
  <option value="3" >Guamiranga</option>
    <option>Carama</option>
  <option  value=" " selected="selected">Todas</option>

</select>
```

Espero que isso ajude.